# Understanding a simple VHDL process

Tags: vhdl

Here is some VHDL code I am given for reading and writing to a memory address that I am trying to understand.  The basic idea is that if we have a rising clock edge and write is enabled (`we = '1'`), then we modify the array called `ram` and store `data` inside.  Then we assign the address from which we just read to `addr_reg`, and then outside the process we assign the contents of `ram` at address `addr_reg` to `q` for reading output.

```
process(clk) begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        if(we = '1') then
            ram(addr) <= data;
        end if;
        -- Register the address for reading
        addr_reg <= addr;
    end if;
end process;

q <= ram(addr_reg);
```

In this case, is the process "slower" than the hardcoded line `q <= ram(addr_reg);`?  In other words, are we reading the previous value at `addr_reg` while simultaneously writing a new value to `addr` such that on the next clock edge that value will be read?  Or is the hardcoded line `q <= ram(addr_reg);` fired after `addr_reg` is assigned in the process, so we are reading the value that we just wrote, namely `data`?

For a complete answer, I'm looking for a detailed explanation of the timeline of events for this code with respect to the clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `rising_edge(clk)` both `ram` and `addr_reg` are updated with the new contents.  The effect of this updated contents is visible right after (a delta cycle) the rising edge of `clk` through the combinatorial `q <= ram(addr_reg)`, which will shown the new values immediately.

So you are reading the value that we just wrote, namely data.  The signals for this case are shown below.

[image]

Comment: Does that mean that addr_reg is pointless here?  Also, is there a difference between the scenarios where `q <= ram(addr_reg);` is included as the last line in the process block (outside the if) and outside the process block?

Comment: You could just as well do `q <= data;` in the last line of the process (and in typical implementation that will be faster and more efficient).   If `q <= ram(addr_reg);` is put as last line in the process, then the update of `q` is postponed until next rising edge, thus delayed a cycle.

Comment: Why would that be the case if `q <= ram(addr_reg);` were in the process block but outside of the if statement that has the rising edge check?

Comment: By "last line in the process" I was supposed to mean inside the `if`, since nothing is placed after the `if`.

Comment: So say it were placed after the if.  Is there any difference between the case when it is inside and outside the process block?

Comment: The process is only executed on changes of the signals in the sensitivity list, and signals are not updated until one delta cycle after assign, which means that placing the assign to `q` after the `if` will postpone the update until new change of `clk`, which will be falling edge.  But synthesis tools are not made to handle that kind of code, so don't do that for implementation.